# Why do I need a certain Rep. to post pictures?

Tags: discussion

I don't get it, I asked a question, and then was asked to post a screenshot. I could not post a screenshot because I don't have a high enough reputation, how does that make sense?

Comment: Give me the link to the Question... And the link to the Image and I will do it for you.

Comment: Welcome to SE.  As you can tell the users here are quite different than other Forums, in that the questions we pose and answer provide reputation.  The thinking is the reputation weeds out the "stupid" answers.  You must earn the rights to do things other Forums take for granted...  Commenting, image posting etc.

Answer (score 6):

Plain and simple: The amount of spam we were getting forced us to put in some new user restrictions.

Just upload the image to http://imgur.com and post a link to it, either in the question (preferable) or in the comments and a higher reputation user will edit it in for you.

This restriction goes away after 10 reputation, you're 2 away from that, [go edit something](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) ;)